# How to initiate integration test project for httpApi Rest Api in Abp Framework

Tags: .net, unit-testing, integration-testing, xunit, abp

I have already Abp framework project without UI. And I am using HttpApi for create rest api

And now i want have integration test for testing this project. But i don't know how to initiate this by using abp cli or creating manually, abp document doesn't mention about creating standalone testing project

Doesn't anyone know to generate Integration Test by abp cli or step by step creating manually. Or any possible way to test controller api ?

how to test http client rest api in httpApi abp framework ? Any possible way create manually or automatically abp integration test for http client rest api ?

Answer (score 0):

The ABP . TestBase package can be used  to write tests that are integrated into the ABP Frameworks. The applications startup template  has base  classes in each test project.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't include integration test httpclient for type "no ui" when i only want write rest api. I saw it have just include for type mvc / blazor